# Connecting serial port via MATLAB App Designer

Tags: matlab, user-interface, arduino, serial-port, matlab-app-designer

I want to connect my Arduino to App Designer by using the "drop down" list. This is what my app looks like

[image: You can see my design here.]

First, I am looking for if there is any serial com. system. And I am writing them to Drop Down.

```
p = instrhwinfo('serial');
app.SerialPortsDropDown.Items = p.AvailableSerialPorts;
```

After this I have planned to read the serial port that is shown in the Drop Down and write it to `serialport()`

```
app.a = serialport(app.SerialPortsDropDown.value,9600);
```

Unfortunately these lines did not work. The error message I got:

> Error using serialport (line 116)
> Unable to connect to the serialport device at port 'COM9'. Verify that
> a device is connected to the port, the port is not in use, and all
> serialport input arguments and parameter values are supported by the
> device.

So, the first two lines of code work. I am able to see COM9 (the com my arduino connected) in the drop-down list. This shows there is a serial port at COM9. But when it comes to reading it with  `app.a = serialport(app.SerialPortsDropDown.value,9600);` it gives error.

How can I connect a serial port via the MATLAB App-designer?

Comment: Can you connect to the Arduino in Matlab without using the App Designer? This would help you know if the problem is with App Designer, or with something else.

Comment: Yes, I can connect without the app designer.  I can also connect with app designer but when it comes to getting com information from the drop down list it is not working. There should be extra codes I guess.

Comment: I guess I solved the problem.
I added the following lines before to declare app.a: 
clear a; 

if ~isempty(instrfind)
    fclose(instrfind);
    delete(instrfind);
end

 But the problem continues. Now I cannot use connected serial port. 
App Designer does not run this simple code line: 
 writeDigitalPin(app.a,'D3',1);
 It is giving this error: 
 Error Undefined function 'writeDigitalPin' for input arguments of type 'internal.Serialport'.
 
Any idea about the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.a = serialport(app.SerialPortsDropDown.value,9600);
```

This is a wrong way of connecting Arduino to MATLAB. This declaration does not let us use Arduino functions such as 'writeDigitalPin, writePWMDutyCycle'.,

As I mentioned in the comments, it is still important to clear the port first and connect the serial port.

Lastly, the true way to declare Arduino to be able to use its functions as in the following:

```
app.a = arduino(app.SerialPortsDropDown.value, 'Tag of your arduino card');
```